# How to set entity in Spring-boot project with Neo4j?

Tags: spring-boot, neo4j

I have something in mind：
If I use **Spring Boot** to build a **Neo4j-based** project, I need to define the properties and methods of the Entity in advance. If I later want to add new edges or attributes to the graph, even new types of nodes, how should I handle entities?

Comment: are you looking for without application restart or server build ? then its not possible currently I guess

Comment: @AkhilSurapuram So if I want to add a new type of node I have to write a new code and restart the application?

Comment: I think you are looking for Repository of Spring data

Answer (score 0):

On Referring the  [Spring Data - Neo4j Docs](https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-neo4j/#initial)

you can write Entities in the following way

Example Entity code:

```
package com.example.accessingdataneo4j;

import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import org.neo4j.ogm.annotation.GeneratedValue;
import org.neo4j.ogm.annotation.Id;
import org.neo4j.ogm.annotation.NodeEntity;
import org.neo4j.ogm.annotation.Relationship;

@NodeEntity
public class Person {

    @Id @GeneratedValue private Long id;

    private String name;

    private Person() {
        // Empty constructor required as of Neo4j API 2.0.5
    };

    public Person(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    /**
     * Neo4j doesn't REALLY have bi-directional relationships. It just means when querying
     * to ignore the direction of the relationship.
     * https://dzone.com/articles/modelling-data-neo4j
     */
    @Relationship(type = "TEAMMATE", direction = Relationship.UNDIRECTED)
    public Set<Person> teammates;

    public void worksWith(Person person) {
        if (teammates == null) {
            teammates = new HashSet<>();
        }
        teammates.add(person);
    }

    public String toString() {

        return this.name + "'s teammates => "
            + Optional.ofNullable(this.teammates).orElse(
                    Collections.emptySet()).stream()
                        .map(Person::getName)
                        .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Edges or Relationships can be done by the following way

```
@Relationship(type = "TEAMMATE", direction = Relationship.UNDIRECTED)
public Set<Person> teammates;
```

Here the person [Node] is connected to another nodes [team-mates] and Stored.

where ever you design you can add new classes and write schema and start the server.

To Perform CRUD operations you can use Spring data jpa Repository.

PersonRepository extends the GraphRepository interface and plugs in the type on which it operates: Person. This interface comes with many operations, including standard CRUD (create, read, update, and delete) operations.

Comment: That is to say, it is impossible to add a new type of node to the graph in real time？

Comment: Node you mean is a Record in nosql Document?